# Why can I run command `scrapy` from mac terminal but not IDLE?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I've downloaded Scrapy via `pip` and am trying to confirm its successfully installed.

If type `scrapy` into the mac terminal it provides the `version name`, `usage`, and `available commands`, so it appears to have installed successfully,

But if type `scrapy` or `import scrapy` into IDLE shell, it returns an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    scrapy NameError: name 'scrapy' is not defined
```

And

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    import scrapy
ImportError: No module named scrapy
```

**What I've tried:**

```
import sys
sys.path
```

And there is no `scrapy` in the printout. So I thought it might be a PATH issue.

So per these docs (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html),
I tried running running,

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

But that results in an error.

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm not really sure where to go with this from here and don't have much experience with python.

Could anyone share ideas that might troubleshoot this?

Comment: Perhaps your issue with different python path in the shell and IDLE is similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/1448173/217088?

Comment: what's the output of `which scrapy` and `which python`

Comment: I suggest to use conda, either anaconda or miniconda: http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

Comment: @eLRull. `which ___ ` for both in IDLE return `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: please run those on terminal

Comment: In the terminal they are both nested in `/anaconda/bin/`